# FastText precision and recall trade-off

Tags: nlp, word2vec, text-analysis, word-embedding, fasttext

In FastText I want to change the balance between precision and recall. Can it be done?

Comment: Are you referring to training, testing, or prediction? AFAIK, FastText ("only," if your question was about training) produces ranked results and defaults to reporting the best label (k=1). You can always report more labels during testing and prediction by setting a larger k: `fasttext predict model.bin test.txt k` - see https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText

Comment: I refer the training. I want to increase the precision even if the recall will reduced.

Comment: k is only refer to the number of labels.

Comment: Yep, that is what I was saying; In that case (directing the model during training to more precision or recall), I think your only option is some C++ hackery of the FastText optimizer/cost function, which is hard-coded to optimizing the softmax with the (label) log likelihood, as one would expect. https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/blob/master/src/model.cc

Comment: @GilLev have you figured out how to control precision/recall? I'm also interested in it and I asked a question on Github too:
https://github.com/facebookresearch/fastText/issues/558

Answer (score 1):

If you're referring to the python fasttext implementation than I'm afraid there is no built in simple method to do this, what you can do is look at the returned probabilities and call an AUC or ROC curve plot method of your choice with the probability lists, here is a code example that does just this for a binary classifier:

```
# label the data
labels, probabilities = fasttext_classifier.predict([re.sub('\n', ' ', sentence) 
                                                     for sentence in test_sentences])

# convert fasttext multilabel results to a binary classifier (probability of TRUE)
labels = list(map(lambda x: x == ['__label__TRUE'], labels))
probabilities = [probability[0] if label else (1-probability[0]) 
                 for label, probability in zip(labels, probabilities)]
```

And then you are free to build your metrics using the common sklearn methods:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_curve
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
from sklearn.metrics import auc
from matplotlib import pyplot

auc = roc_auc_score(testy, probabilities)
print('ROC AUC=%.3f' % (auc))

# calculate roc curve
fpr, tpr, _ = roc_curve(testy, probabilities)

# plot the roc curve for the model
pyplot.plot(fpr, tpr, marker='.', label='ROC curve')
# axis labels
pyplot.xlabel('False Positive Rate (sensitivity)')
pyplot.ylabel('True Positive Rate (specificity)')
# show the legend
pyplot.legend()
# show the plot
pyplot.show()

precision_values, recall_values, _ = precision_recall_curve(testy, probabilities)
f1 = f1_score(testy, labels)
# summarize scores
print('f1=%.3f auc=%.3f' % (f1, auc))
# plot the precision-recall curves
pyplot.plot(recall_values, precision_values, marker='.', label='Precision,Recall')
# axis labels
pyplot.xlabel('Recall')
pyplot.ylabel('Precision')
# show the legend
pyplot.legend()
# show the plot
pyplot.show()
```

The command line fasttext version has a threshold parameter and you can perform multiple runs with different thresholds but this is needlessly time consuming.

Comment: I know it is very old post, but i was wondering how to generate testy from loaded model?

Comment: labels, probabilities = fasttext_classifier.predict(...) like in this line of my code?

Comment: yes, `testy`is not explained how did you map it in your _fasttext_ model results. Would you please show complete example after running the _fasttext_ model in your data for binary classifications and plotting the results of ROC and AUC?